# React Navigation using a native stack navigator with a slide animation in a partial view

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, slide, android-transitions, react-navigation-stack

I'm creating a React Native application, and I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) to navigate between screens. However, a part of my application is static (in my case, the main application bar, not related to the navigator) on the left. I'm using a [Native Stack Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator) (but I can switch to a classic Stack Navigator if necessary, but I did not managed to get it working) with a `slide_from_right` animation.

The problem is that the app bar on the left gets covered with the screen content during the transition. I'd like to find a workaround to prevent that... Note: This behavior only occurs on Android.

I made a simple Snack to illustrate the issue: https://snack.expo.dev/j_Z0RwYzu?platform=android

Here is the code of the Snack in case it's no longer accessible:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function Home({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Home Page</Text>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
        title="Go to settings"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function Settings({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Settings Page</Text>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'lightblue' }}>
          <Text>Global Info</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
              headerShown: false,
              animation: 'slide_from_right',
              presentation: 'card',
            }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: you want like this! if you click home page then it's navigate with right side ?

Comment: I want the transitions (both from the right and the left, because the `goBack` action reverse the animation) not to overlap on the left section (which is static and does not change). I want the same behavior as iOS on Android (see the Snack for a demo)

Comment: here you can see commented code maybe this will help you with what you want https://github.com/DharaSapariya5/TextUtils_App/blob/main/src/Router.js